# Issues with UISearchController. How to correctly present the search results on a new table

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisearchcontroller, ios9.2

I have two controllers: the main one is `LocationItemTableViewController` and contains all the graphic elements and the unfiltered table; the other one is `SearchResultsTableViewController`, which is used to process the results of the search. I want the search results to be displayed on `LocationItemTableViewController`, in a new table.

When the search starts `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` is called on the main controller and this assigns the results of the search to `resultsController` (an instance of `SearchResultsTableViewController`) which displays them on the main view controller.

Issues:

- When `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` is called my `NavigationBar` unexpectedly disappears! Why?
- When `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` is called the results are displayed correctly but if I scroll them up they pass underneath the `SearchBar` and then they show up again where there should be the `NavigationBar`..
- When I click on a button that I have implemented in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it gives me this warning:

**Warning: Attempt to present UIAlertController: xxxxxxx on LocationItemTableViewController: xxxxxx whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

The button is supposed to call a kind of action sheet (`UIAlertController`) on `LocationItemTableViewController`.

Clearly there is something conceptually wrong in what I am doing but I cannot understand what...
Any hint please? Thanks!

**LocationItemTableViewController.h**

```
@interface LocationItemTableViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UIAlertViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSCoding, UIActionSheetDelegate>
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *filteredLocationItemArray; //Filtered results array
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *NavigationBar;
```

**LocationItemTableViewController.m**

```
@interface LocationItemTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SearchResultsTableViewController *resultsController;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.LocationItemArray count]];

    resultsController = [[SearchResultsTableViewController alloc] init];
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:resultsController];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

    self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = nil;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;

    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y + NavigationBar.bounds.size.height +20,  self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height);
}

-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

    NSString *searchString = [self.searchController.searchBar text];

    NSString *scope = nil;

    [self updateFilteredContentForProductName:searchString type:scope];

    if (self.searchController.searchResultsController) {

        resultsController.filteredEvents = self.searchResults;

        resultsController.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-ToolBar.bounds.size.height);

        //Now reload the table but this time containing the search results
        [resultsController.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

**SearchResultsTableViewController.h**

```
@interface SearchResultsTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *filteredEvents;
```

**SearchResultsTableViewController.m**

```
@interface SearchResultsTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) LocationItemTableViewController *instanceOfLocationItemTableViewController;
@end

@implementation SearchResultsTableViewController
@synthesize instanceOfLocationItemTableViewController;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Create instance of LocationItemTableViewController.h
    instanceOfLocationItemTableViewController = [[LocationItemTableViewController alloc] init];

    [self.tableView setAllowsSelection:NO];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return self.filteredEvents ? 1 : 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"CALLED numberOfRowsInSection --: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.filteredEvents count]);

    return [self.filteredEvents count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Create a new LocationItem Object
    LocationItem *locationItem = nil;
    locationItem = [self.filteredEvents objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SearchResultCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    ....
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[locationItem name]];

    return cell;
}
```